# Using For-Loop in a Panda DataFrame (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df) in **Python** with a few features but I'm going to work with `Age` and `Age_Mean` columns.

In `Age` column, there are several `null` values. I would like to replace those null values with the same index from `Age_Mean` column.

Here is the code I used:

```py
    for i in df:
        if df['Age'].isnull().iloc[i] == True:
            df['Age'].iloc[i] == df['Age_Mean'].iloc[i]
```

This is my error message:

> KeyError: 'the label [Age] is not in the [index]'

Please let me know what is wrong with this code.

Comment: What error are you getting? - Just saying "I get error" doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Her is the error I get: ```KeyError: 'the label [Age] is not in the [index]'```

Comment: Can you give some example data? And why aren't you just using `df['Age'].fillna(df['Age_Mean'])`?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question including both the example and error.

Comment: @NilsWerner Thank you very much Nils. Yes I could use your code as well, but I tried to understand the issue with for-loop and thanks to Parthasarathy, I found out about my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `for i in df` will iterate through the column name. Let's take an example to understand this better:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Age":np.array([2,3,np.nan,8,np.nan]),"Age_mean":np.array([2,5,9,2,1])})
df
```

so the data frame will look like this:

```
    Age Age_mean
0   2.0 2
1   3.0 5
2   NaN 9
3   8.0 2
4   NaN 1
```

Now lets see what the for loop will iterate over:

```
for i in df:
     print(i)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Age
Age_mean
```

And now when you try to execute `df['Age'].isnull().iloc[i]` it is going to throw an error because the value of `i` will be `Age` in this case.

**PROPOSED SOLUTION:**

We can do this without a for loop as shown below:

```
nan_index = df['Age'].index[df['Age'].apply(np.isnan)]
df.loc[nan_index,"Age"] = df.loc[nan_index,"Age_mean"]
```

The first line is going to return the indices of the rows for which the value of `Age` is `NaN`. Once we know that we just to replace those with the value in the column `Age_mean` which is done by the second statement.

**OUTPUT**

```
    Age Age_mean
0   2.0 2
1   3.0 5
2   9.0 9
3   8.0 2
4   1.0 1
```